# itgendch023: Backing database of Data Cache could not be opened

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online, invantive-sql

I've configured Invantive Data Cache on my connection to Exact Online Belgium. It connects fine. But when I run the following query (for example) as a first query:

```
select * from me
```

I get a:

```
Backing database of Data Cache could not be opened.
Er is een netwerkfout of een exemplaarspecifieke fout opgetreden tijdens het maken van verbinding met SQL Server. De server is niet gevonden of is niet toegankelijk. Controleer of de exemplaarnaam correct is en of in de instellingen van SQL Server externe verbindingen zijn toegestaan. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Kon geen verbinding met SQL Server openen)
Kan het netwerkpad niet vinden
```

## Configuration

I've configured the connection as follows in settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3" forcedefault="false">
  <group name="Data Cache">
    <connection name="EOL-be-data cache" manual="true" dataCacheConnectionString="provider=SqlServer;connectionString={Server=server.com;Database=ods;User Id=ods;Password=secret}">
      <database order="0" provider="ExactOnlineAll" connectionString="apiUrl=https://start.exactonline.be" />
    </connection>
  </group>
</settings>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you configure the connection in settings.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check the following:

- The user 'ods' has the privilege to create tables and views in the database 'ods' (dbowner is fine).
- The user 'ods' can connect to the server (there is no firewall blocking it).

Based upon the error, I think there is a firewall block active.

On the privileges for user `ods`, please refer to your local DBA and point him for instance to [DBA article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69135/what-does-role-db-owner-allow).

The connection to the cloud data replicator database is only opened on the first query or action, not on initial log on to the cloud platform.

To load all available tables, the logical next step would be:

```
alter persistent cache load
```

and to refresh:

```
alter persistent cache refresh
```

That saves you a lot of maintenance on the repository.

Using `local data cache` you can get a GUI to confgiure it.

Comment: Thx, I will have it checked.